# Reading fif file with mne.io.read_file raises an exception

Tags: python, mne-python

I'm trying to read a .fif file with mne.io.read_file method:

```
mne.io.read_raw_fif("./data/emotions_binary/p0109.fif", preload = True)
```

and i'm getting ValueError:
cannot reshape array of size 1883 into shape (250,8).

Anybody faced with that kind of errors? What to do with it and what causes this exception?

With most files everything is alright, just a couple give this exception.